# Custom keyboard shortcuts for NON-UNIQUE menu items in Mac Outlook

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to create a keyboard shortcut to "Create a task" from a message. I do NOT want to "Flag" it, flagged messages do not show up on Microsoft Todo (which I use as my task manager), but "tasks" do.

I know that we can create custom shortcuts on Outlook [as per this documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-custom-keyboard-shortcut-for-Office-for-Mac-6bbeb90e-96d9-4e03-b199-fc026ebdc321), but it seems to only work for "unique" menu items. E.g. in my case, the menu item is "Task", under "Messages > Create > Task", but there is another "Task" under "File > New > Task".

[image: multiple "Tasks" in menu]

I have tried various combinations of "Menu Titles" ("Create > Task", "Message > Create > Task", but nothing seems to work. When I just put "Task", it maps it to the "File > New > Task"

[image: Keyboard shortcuts]

Does anyone know how I could map the shortcut to this non-unique menu item, i.e. "Create > Task"?

Comment: Try `Message->Create->Task` no spaces. If no joy, try it as an 'All Apps' shortcut rather than Outlook specific.

Comment: How about Control + Equal sign ( = ) to flag the selected item for follow up, and add a reminder. I don't have a Mac so I cannot test this for you. I did test this in Outlook for Windows, message flagged with a reminder showed up in my To-Do list.

Comment: @Tetsujin No dice - did not work :(

Comment: @SteveFan Thanks for the shortcut - that does make my life a bit easier. But it did not create a "Task", which is what seems to sync with Microsoft To-do.

Comment: You copy/pasted exactly as written? That's been the accepted method since Lion, though I don't have Outlook to test on.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a shortcut, I used an alternative approach to achieve my goal, because:

1. I could not figure out a way to add a shortcut to create a task, since it seems either MS or Apple does not support non-unique menu items.
2. "Creating a task" is not supported on Outlook Mobile, which only supports "schedule" and "flag".

I setup a [Microsoft Flow, an Office version of "IFTTT"](https://flow.microsoft.com) that accepts a "When an email is flagged" in Outlook as a trigger, and then performs an action of "Add a To-do" in Microsoft To-do.

This alternative approach solves both my problems. Hope this helps others who have the same requirement as I did!

[image: Microsoft Flow setup]